# Circular buffer implementation in C

Tags: c, data-structures, circular-buffer

I have found pseudo code on how to implement a circular buffer.

```c
// Producer.
while (true) {
  /* produce item v */
  while ((in+1)%n == out)
    /* Wait. */;
  b[in] = v;
  in = (in + 1) % n
}

// Consumer.
while (true) {
  while (in == out)
    /* Wait. */;
  w = b[out];
  out = (out + 1) % n;
  /* Consume item w. */
}
```

What I don't understand is the "Consume item w." comment, because I think that with `w = b[out];` we are consuming `w`, aren't we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With

```
w = b[out];
```

You only grab a copy of the item to be consumed.  With

```
out = (out + 1) % n;
```

You advance the index of the item to be consumed, thereby preventing it from being referenced again.

In a manner, multiple calls to `w = b[out];` don't actually consume the buffer's slot, it just accesses it; while `out = (out + 1) % n;` prevents further access of that item.  Preventing further access of the buffer item is the strongest definition of the term "consume the item" that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

these two lines are both part of consuming process:

```
w = b[out];
out = (out + 1) % n;
```

The first extract the value and the second increment the out index.
The comment refers to the previously two lines.

Comment: when it says `/* produce item v */` we need to assign v to a random number or something like that.. i thought we need a different process for `  /* Consume item w. */ `

Comment: consume an item means retrieve it's value and no longer access it.

Comment: "The comment refers to the previously two lines." - which, I'd add, ought to be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because then it's out of the buffer, which the following row says is empty.
Then we can process w.